# FLUSHALL and FLUSHDB commands on redis return "unk command"

Tags: redis

To flush redis, the `FLUSHALL` command is to be used.

Using Redis 2.6.16, when I tried both `FLUSHALL` and `FLUSHDB` commands while using redis-cli, I got an `unknown command` error. Other commands work fine.

a) What is going wrong with the `FLUSH*` commands?

b) Is a workaround to do a shutdown of Redis, then delete the rdb file? (I believe so)

UPDATE:

No, we never solved this.

(The only known solution is to use step 'b' above)

Comment: Your assumption (b) is correct. Regarding (a); what's wrong with your commands: very strange, I haven't got a clue. Did you do a `make` and a `make test`? There must be st wrong with your build.

Comment: Yes, I did the whole make/make test on initial install a year ago. This is a production instance that works fine in all other ways.

Comment: same problem here; did you solve?

Comment: Same problem, anybody have solution?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It could be that your Redis configuration has renamed some commands to prevent your database from being accidentaly deleted.

Look for the following lines in your redis.conf:

```
rename-command FLUSHDB ""
rename-command FLUSHALL ""
```

Comment: Just a note: this is a server setting, not client ;)

Comment: This is the default in the Bitnami Redis kubernetes helm chart, for anyone else using that and running into this surprise. Undo by modifying the `master/slave.disableCommands` value.

Answer (score 42):

[Redis official Helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/redis#parameters) by default disables `FLUSHDB` and `FLUSHALL` commands. In this case, it is not specified in any of the `redis.conf` inside the containers, so you need to specify it in your Redis YAML:

```
master:
  disableCommands: []
```

Comment: Please note that it is specified in the `values.yaml` file - for both master and slaves

Comment: In the end we did not enable the commands, instead we executed the following command in the shell of the Redis container provided by Bitnami:

`echo 'KEYS *' | redis-cli * | sed 's/^/DEL /' | redis-cli`

Comment: I think there is a small typo, the * near the redis-cli is not needed.
The command should be like that:
`echo 'KEYS *' | redis-cli | sed 's/^/DEL /' | redis-cli`

Answer (score 6):

I was using Helm and didn't want to go through reinstalling it, so I worked around this issue by modifying the configmap that Helm generates to contain the config.

```
CONFIGMAP=<<value of common.names.fullname>>-configuration
kubectl edit cm $CONFIGMAP
```

You should see something like:

```
  master.conf: |-
    dir /data
    # User-supplied master configuration:
    rename-command FLUSHDB ""
    rename-command FLUSHALL ""
    # End of master configuration
  redis.conf: |-
    # User-supplied common configuration:
    # Enable AOF https://redis.io/topics/persistence#append-only-file
    appendonly yes
    # Disable RDB persistence, AOF persistence already enabled.
    save ""
    # End of common configuration
  replica.conf: |-
    dir /data
    slave-read-only yes
    # User-supplied replica configuration:
    rename-command FLUSHDB ""
    rename-command FLUSHALL ""
    # End of replica configuration
```

Remove lines beginning with `rename-command` so it looks more like this:

```
  master.conf: |-
    dir /data
    # User-supplied master configuration:
    # End of master configuration
  redis.conf: |-
    # User-supplied common configuration:
    # Enable AOF https://redis.io/topics/persistence#append-only-file
    appendonly yes
    # Disable RDB persistence, AOF persistence already enabled.
    save ""
    # End of common configuration
  replica.conf: |-
    dir /data
    slave-read-only yes
    # User-supplied replica configuration:
    # End of replica configuration
```

Restart the redis pods

```
kubectl delete pods $(kubectl get pods | grep redis | awk {'print $1'})
```

Now exec into the master pod and flush all

```
kubectl exec redis-master-0 -- redis-cli FLUSHALL
OK
```

Be aware that you will have to do this again if you reinstall your Helm release if you want to use FLUSHALL or FLUSHDB again.

Update:  Although this works, when you go to reinstall your helm release the pods will go into crashloopbackoff because they will see in the history that the commands you ran don't exist, so you will have to go through this again to get the pods to run.  Probably best to go with @camilo-sampedro's answer in this case.