# Command missing in redis / symfony

Tags: php, symfony, redis

Has anyone gone through this ?

Command "redis:flushdb" is not defined.
Command "redis:flushall" is not defined.

But all other redis command are working ?

I have sncRedisBundle 4.4.2 installed, when running bin/console redis:flushdb, error above.

Updated sncRedisBundle from 3.6 to 4.4.2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FLUSHALL and FLUSHDB commands on redis return "unk command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815364/flushall-and-flushdb-commands-on-redis-return-unk-command)

Comment: Thanks for the link but it does seem that it doesnt apply to my case. I am running a symfony project in which i've installed sncRedisBundle. This manages everything for me but apparently not those two functions